Do we already have the necessary code for antibodies against various diseases?
Whenever we get exposed to a particular antigen, we form antibodies against it. Doesn't this suggest that we already have the genetic code to code an antibody against that particular antigen? If not so how are we able to form a new antibody as soon as we are exposed to an antigen?

Famously "The immune system is very complicated ...". You may want to consult a good popular book on the immune system like An Elegant Defense.
There is a portion of the region of the genome responsible for the building antibodies called the V(D)J recombination region. V(D)J stands for "variable–diversity–joining". At a certain stage in the division and development of some white blood cells, these segments of DNA rearrange themselves in a more or less random fashion. Antibodies share most of their structure with other antibodies, but this variable region is the bit of DNA that codes for the part of the antibody that binds to antigens. So you end up with  white blood cells that can generate different antibodies that will bind to different antigens.
There are many different types of "white blood cells", all playing different roles in the immune response. But very roughly, if a white blood cell doesn't happen to encounter a protein that matches its antibody, it will eventually die, and that particular version of the antibody will be forgotten. If it does encounter the matching protein it will trigger a complex feedback loop, which will result in the white blood cell with the "right" antibody" reproducing at a massive scale, pouring out antibodies and attacking the pathogen that had the foreign protein. After the pathogen is killed off, some of the white blood cells specific to it will hang around, and be ready to go if you encounter that pathogen again.
Note that we do not form new antibodies as soon as we are exposed to an antigen. It's a matter of chance how long it takes for the correct antibody to be formed, and how long it takes for it to encounter its antigen. This means there may be a period when the pathogen is rapidly growing within you, but you have no or limited immune response to it. If the pathogen causes disease, you may die before your immune system is able to catch up, or because the immune response is so large that it starts damaging your body itself.
This is why vaccines are so valuable. They expose your body to the antigens associated with a pathogen, but there is no danger of the pathogen replicating and killing you. This gives you the time you need to develop a healthy immune response to that pathogen

In contrast to Charles’ technical answer, here is a simplified version.
Yes, our bodies already have the code on how most of the antibody should be shaped; that is apart from the most crucial part which recognises the pathogen (let's call it the recognition part, RP). The original 'template' for RP is pretty much the same in all cells that go on to produce antibodies in our body, but each of these cells warps the 'template' in an individual way, leading to a large number of randomly reshuffled versions.
The body first has to notice the antigen and move it to the lymph nodes, where cells can then test various RP shapes until they find one that works!

Why the downvotes?

Perhaps because there is no code, in the recognized sense of the word, and talking about the body “knowing” is the worst kin of anthropomorphism.

Because instead of stating it more simply, you've dumbed it down to a terrible answer?

Sorry, if any of you could come up with a good edit, I will happily accept it

@Harrychink You should look at other answers and try to model what they do - add references and links for people to find out more. You should also use proper terms. Charles' answer isn't highly technical at all; the most complex bit is the V(D)J part and even that has a link to explain it. I would expect a late high-school student (say last 3 years of high school) to be able to understand the content in there without difficulty.
